# How to change date and time(CSV file) in standard format(yyyy-mm-ddthh:mm:ss+00:00)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, backtrader

I had a data in which it has only Date(yyyy-mm-dd) and time(hh.mm). I am getting an error for datetime format does not match.

I want to convert my existing data into standard format using python(Pandas) library.Please give a proper solution for it.

data = btfeeds.GenericCSVData(
dataname='2017 BNF.csv',

```
fromdate=datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 3),
todate=datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 10),

nullvalue=0.0,

dtformat=('%Y-%m-%d'),
tmformat=('%H:%M'),

datetime=0,
time=1,
open=2,
high=3,
low=4,
close=5,
openinterest=-1
```

)
ValueError: time data '2017-01-02T10' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'

Input(csv) : 2017-01-02,09:08
Expected output:2017-01-02 09:08:00+05:30

Comment: Which error? on which input? You need to provide enough details to reproduce your issue to help you and also make your question useful for future readers.

Comment: Sample input and expected output would help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give some sample code, input, expected output and the exact error message? You have given the error in a comment, but if you could add it, and what produces this error, to the body of your question. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This is because the format you need to ask for **does not** contain seconds.

1. correct format: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M`
2. incorrect format: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:S`

So this would work:

```py
import datetime as dt
x =  '2017-01-02T09:08'

datetime_object = dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

print(datetime_object)
```

And the result (of the print statement) would be this:

```
2017-01-02 09:08:00
```

Comment: how do you mean please ?   i reproduce the same error message and then able to correct that error message with the above...

Comment: so the question is:  how to combine a date and time into a single date time ?

Comment: For now I had not combined date and time

Comment: No read my title in question

Comment: I already had data(downloaded) but it is not in default form so I had to make changes